# ALAssest of an Image taken from Camera without saving it

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, alasset

Hi I was wondering if theres a way to extract ALAsset of an image taken from Camera but without saving it... 
Ive come across various example that used writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum and then fetched the ALAssest, but i dont deem it necessary to save the image in the camera roll, was just wondering if this could be done otherwise

Comment: What's wrong with using the image that would be passed to `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`?

Comment: Nothing wrong per say Wain!! but the assumption is that the image is just taken for the purpose of loading the image into app, storing it in camera would hog up memory by storing an image that otherwise wouldnt be required by the user anyways.

Comment: Ummm Its a one time use image... hope no confusions in there!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `ALAssest` exists until the image has been successfully saved to the image library. Until then you just have a `UIImage` that has come from the picker. There is no mandate that the image needs to be saved into the library and any decision about whether you want to save the image should be based on what the app tells the user and if the user would naturally expect to find the image in the library after taking / saving it in the app.

Comment: Hmmm you're right the images can be saved in custom album if taken via camera presented thru app.